# How to ask a question about ordinal number?

Tags: word-usage, questions

There are many pupils in the classroom. Peter was the n th( n is a positive integer) student to arrive. Now I want to ask Peter about what n is. How can I ask him?
It seems that it is very difficult to begin with a wh- question in situations like this.

As I have noticed previous similar questions about this.

`Where did Peter fall in the sequence of arrival?`

Is this idiomatic ?

Comment: "Peter, how many pupils arrived before you?"

Comment: How about: When did you arrive in relation to your peers/the rest of the class?

Comment: related: 1. [How to ask a question to get an ordinal number answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21876/how-to-ask-a-question-to-get-an-ordinal-number-answer) 2. [Framing a question whose answer is an ordinal number](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11481/framing-a-question-whose-answer-is-an-ordinal-number)

Comment: 3. [How should I phrase a question that must be answered with an ordinal number (e.g., the third prime)?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/13662/how-should-i-phrase-a-question-that-must-be-answered-with-an-ordinal-number-e-g)

Comment: This topic is brought up often here. I can find at least five examples: [How-to-ask-about-ordinal-place-of-an-offspring](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/131683), [How-to-ask-nth-time-of-something](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/47107), [How-to-phrase-a-question-that-must-be-answered-with-an-ordinal-number](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/13662), [Framing-a-question-whose-answer-is-an-ordinal-number](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11481), [Returning-for-the-nth-time](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/102996)

Comment: The first question has links to the other two questions. Between all three of them you can find your answer. Just use a little common sense, e.g. swap "birth order" with "order/sequence of arrival" etc. Is it idiomatic? Not terribly, but it's English and it's understandable and it's one question. Deadrat's suggestion would not supply an ordinal number, but a cardinal one e.g. Five students arrived before Peter.